# AmazonS3: custom error pages

Tags: amazon-s3, standards, conventions

I am planning to share URLs (time limited) for private objects. Is there a way to set custom error pages for 404/403 http responses ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, see [this announcement](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/02/17/Amazon-S3-Website-Features/). 
In the [Developer guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?WebsiteHosting.html) there is a paragraph about "Custom Error Document Support" where I read the following sentence.

> You can optionally provide a custom
>   error document with a user-friendly
>   error message and with additional
>   help. You provide this custom error
>   document as part of adding website
>   configuration to your bucket. Amazon
>   S3 returns your custom error document
>   for only the HTTP 4XX class of error
>   codes.

How to set 4xx custom error page:

- With [CloudBerry](http://cloudberrylab.com/), you can right click on a bucket, select Properties, click the tab Website and set the index document and the 4xx error document.
- Use [AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), here is an example code (not tested)

  ```
  AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(
      "accessKey", "secretKey");
  BucketWebsiteConfiguration conf = new BucketWebsiteConfiguration(
      "index.html", "404.html");
  client.setBucketWebsiteConfiguration("bucketname.example.com", conf);
  ```

**UPDATE** I also found this blog post: [Host Your Static Website on Amazon S3](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html).

Comment: This is all available in the AWS console now, under S3. Click on a bucket, then click on the properties tab for the bucket on the right. You'll see a "Static Website Hosting" section with this config. https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/