# Amazon S3 Redirect rule for objects with trailing slash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Static Website Hosting is activated.

Is it possible to redirect Amazon S3 objects which consists of trailing forward slashes using redirection rules?

From my understanding when a trailing forward slash object is accessed in the browser (basically a "directory"), S3 defaults to index.html within the directory. However, many of the directories do not consist of an index.html. The "directory" without the trailing slash redirects like expected to the Error Document explicitly set. Accessing the object with the trailing slash will download an empty object, which I am trying to avoid. Preferably I would like to redirect the trailing slash object to the error document.

Comment: Possibly relayed to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500138/amazons3-custom-error-pages

Comment: @mickzer Thanks for the response, but this doesn't solve the issue. Custom error pages will work when a directory is accessed without the trailing slash (ex: `http://www.foo.com/bar`), but on urls with the trailing slash (ex: `http://www.foo.com/bar/`) it does not work. Edit: SO removes trailing slashes in URLs....

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is an S3 issue.

You might be able to workaround the issue using a Lambda@Edge script, but this will increase costs.

If you use Cloudflare or something similar, you can add some redirection rules. Add / before ? and add more rules about parameter you need. Which helped to me.
I just add in Cloudflare URL Query string => contain => utm string params

My recommendation would be to make sure all your marketing campaigns include the trailing slash. This will make your site load faster as well, because it removes one round trip.