# Angular pre-rendered pages giving 302 redirect

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, prerender

I'm getting a 302 redirect on all of my pre-rendered angular (v15) pages. I'm serving the static site from cloudfront uploading the pre-rendered pages into s3.

example.com/route looks like it's being redirected to example.com/route/ which then leverages the pre-rendered example.com/route/index.html

As a confirmation, example.com/route/ gives me a normal 200 status.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the redirect without the trailing '/'? Or is the better fix to make canonical links all have the trailing '/'?

Answer (score 0):

Update: It looks like this is an S3 issue in how it handles trailing slash vs non-trailing slash requests.

Sounds like the best practice is to make canonical links and marketing links include the trailing slash to prevent a 302 redirect loop. Alternatively, can create a lambda@edge script that adds trailing slashes to non-file requests

[Amazon S3 Redirect rule for objects with trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759268/amazon-s3-redirect-rule-for-objects-with-trailing-slash)